# Read sets from database table

Tags: database, ampl

I have two sets `A` and `B`, set `B` depends on set `A`;

```
set A;
set B{A};
```

In my database I have two tables - `A_Table` with primary key `a_id` and table `B_Table` with composite key `b_id` and `a_id` (foreign key). I tried to read data from `B_Table` table to set `B` using this script:

```
table B_Table IN "ODBC" (ConnectionStr) "B_Table":
   [b ~ b_id, a ~ a_id], B[a] ~ b;
```

But this script doesn't work. It writes

```
syntax error
context:  [b ~ b_id, a ~ a_id],  >>> B[ <<< a] ~ b;
```

How can I read data from a table that has 2 key to a one-dimentional set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can read the data directly into an indexed set using a single table declaration, but you can use a helper two-dimensional set:

```
set AB dimen 2;
table B_Table IN "ODBC" (ConnectionStr) "B_Table":
   AB <- [a_id, b_id];
read table B_Table;
let{a in A} B[a] := setof{(a, b) in AB} b;
```

Another option is to make the table declaration indexed over `A` and use an SQL statement to select data for `a in A`:

```
table B_Table{a in A} IN "ODBC" (ConnectionStr)
  ("SQL=SELECT b_id FROM B_Table WHERE a_id = " & a & ";"):
   B[a] <- [b_id];
```

or something like that.